# no module named packaging.version

Tags: pip

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 yesterday and installed pip by the command
`sudo apt-get install python-pip`,
later when I am trying to install other packages through pip or trying to check the pip version, I am getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in module  
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point  
  File "/home/abhi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 70, in module  
    import packaging.version  
ImportError: No module named packaging.version
```

I tried by installing pip3, but that also gives the same error.

Comment: I strongly recommend using [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads#linux). In addition to providing python and pip it provides pre-built versions of many packages and virtual environment management. Simply install anaconda, create a virtual environment with the desired python version and then use pip as usual. I realize this does not answer your question but I hope it will help you get around the issue

Answer (score 1):

I solved the above problem by installing pip by the following command

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

Now pip is working fine..

Comment: Hi, I had the same problem as the OP (though with python3.4). How can your solution work if pip(3) fails ?

Comment: It gives me this error : `/usr/bin/python: No module named packaging.version; 'pip' is a package and cannot be directly executed`

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to reinstall pip using the [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) script, as described [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/):

```
sudo apt-get purge python-pip python-setuptools
curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
```